# Need GKE Deployment Failed Logs in GCP Logging

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, logging, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

we need to get k8S Deployment Failed logs using GCP Logging Query

Tried Below  GCP logging Query but not sure how to get failed Deployment logs using this

`resource.type="k8s_cluster" AND log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity") AND protoPayload.methodName:"deployments"`

Comment: Also tried with resource.type="k8s_cluster"
resource.labels.cluster_name="hello-cluster"
resource.labels.location="us-west1"
protoPayload.request.metadata.name="hello-server"
protoPayload.methodName:"deployments." this GCP logging Query Not able to get Failed Deployments

Answer (score 0):

could be please try the below and see if this will help you

```
resource.type="k8s_cluster" AND log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity") AND protoPayload.methodName:"deployments" AND protoPayload.response.status.code = "FAILED"
```

This query will search for log entries in GCP related to Kubernetes clusters that have failed deployments.Let me know if you were looking for something else.

Comment: Thankyou for your Answer Exactly this we are loooking for but How did you got this protoPayload.response.status.code =failed In My logs status code sometimes it was null or zero